# Jquery - hide <hr /> and <h2> before <div> if there isn't text inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty

Is it possible to hide `hr` with class name `event-title(number)` and `h2` with class name `event-title(number)` before `div` if `div` with class name `events-container(number)` is without text?

Code:

```
{section name=MainOffice loop=$MainOffice}
   <h2 class="event-title1">{$MainOffice[MainOffice].offCountry}</h2><br />
   {* Hide if div events-container1 is without text *}
{/section}
<div class="events-container1">
  {* Example content1 *}
</div>
<hr class="event-line1" /> {* Hide if events-container1 is without text *}
<h2 class="event-title2">Online</h2> {* Hide if events-container2 is without text *}
<br />
<div class="events-container2">
  {* Example content2 *}
</div>
<hr class="event-line2" /> {* Hide if events-container2 is without text *}
<h2 class="event-title3">International</h2> {* Hide if events-container3 is without text *}
<br />
<div class="events-container3">
  {* Example content3 *}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separator in your naming (`event-title_2`) so selection of the elements is done easier. For the solution I'm working on a fiddle that I'll post ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if ($('.events-container(number)').val() == '') {
    $('.event-title(number)').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `hide class` in hr and h2 if div has empty text like,

```
<div class="events-container1">
  {* Example content1 *}
</div>
{if ((isset($content1)) && ($content1 != ''))} {$hide=''} 
{else} {$hide='hide'} {/if}

<hr class="event-line1 {$hide}" /> {* Hide if events-container1 is without text *}
```

Or in jquery it can be simple like,

```
$(function(){
   var $container=$('div[class^="events-container"]:empty'); //get empty div
   $container.each(function(i,v){ // loop for all containers
       var num=this.className.replace('events-container',''); //get class number
       $('.event-line'+num+',.event-title'+num).hide();// hide h2 and hr acc to num
   });
});
```

Read [start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [:empty-selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

Comment: I don't get it content1 is not variable.

Comment: I assumed `$content1` as variable you can use `{* Example content1 *}` whatever the variable name is.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work without the need to modify anything in your code.

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("[class^='event-title']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).next("[class^='events-container']").is(':empty')) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<h2 class="event-title-1">One</h2>
<div class="events-container1">div one</div>

<h2 class="event-title-2">Im hidden cause next div is empty</h2>
<div class="events-container2"></div>

<h2 class="event-title-3">three</h2>
<div class="events-container3">div thee</div>
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/q0b5qdfn/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code:

```
$("h2").filter(function() {
        var i = this.className.match(/event-title(\d)/)
        if(i != null){
            i = i[1] ; 
            return $("div.events-container"+i).html().length == 0;
        } else return false;
    }).hide()

$("hr").filter(function() {
        var i = this.className.match(/event-line(\d)/)
        if(i != null){
            i = i[1] ; 
            return $("div.events-container"+i).html().length == 0;
        } else return false;
    }).hide()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xu18fqr5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Separate each section with a class name (events-container in my example) and the inner content div with another class name (content-container in my example), then loop each events-container, check the contents-container div for text, and hide if there is none.

```
$(function() {
    $(".events-container").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).closest('div').next().find('.content-container').text()) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

See my working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbetke/mwvtmvd1/) where I have commented out content in the third container and it hides the div on the page load.